# Docker: Trying to connect to a database which is in another server from node app hosted in docker

Tags: oracle, docker, node-oracledb

I have a node app hosted in docker. I need to connect to a oracledb which is in a server  from this dockerized app. To fulfil this I followed the tutorial: [Node_Oracledb](https://learncodeshare.net/2019/08/27/howto-connect-your-nodejs-app-in-docker-to-your-oracle-database/)

Error I get is

*[Error: ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA] {
errorNum: 12504,
offset: 0
}
connection is not defined*

Now I am not sure this error is coming from docker or server. Following is the code

I am very new to docker and I have tried my best to get help online from many other sources but it didnt solve the issue. Any help would be great.

**dbConfig.js**

```
module.exports = {
user          : process.env.NODE_ORACLEDB_USER,
password      : process.env.NODE_ORACLEDB_PASSWORD,
connectString : process.env.NODE_ORACLEDB_CONNECTIONSTRING,
poolMax: 2,
poolMin: 2,
poolIncrement: 0
```

};

**Dockerfile**

```
# bring latest node in alpine linux image
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim
# app directory
WORKDIR /app
#copy pacakge*.json files
COPY package*.json ./

# Update Oracle Linux
# Install Node.js
# Install the Oracle Instant Client
# Check that Node.js and NPM installed correctly
# Install the OracleDB driver
RUN yum update -y && \
yum install -y oracle-release-el7 && \
yum install -y oracle-nodejs-release-el7 && \
yum install -y nodejs && \
yum install -y oracle-instantclient19.3-basic.x86_64 && \
yum clean all && \
node --version && \
npm --version && \
npm install && \
echo Installed

# Copy project
COPY . .

EXPOSE 9090

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const dbConfig = require('./dbConfig.js');
const app = express();

oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT;
oracledb.autoCommit = true;

async function getData(req, res) {
    try {
        connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);
        data = await connection.execute(`SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENT`)
    } catch (error) {
        return res.send(error.message)
    } finally {
        try {
            await connection.close();
            console.log('Connection closed');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message)
        }
    }
    if (data.rows.length == 0) {
        return res.send('No data found');
    } else {
        return res.status(200).json({
            data: data.rows, 
        })
    }
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    getData(req, res);
})
```

**exports**

```
export NODE_ORACLEDB_USER=NotMyRealUser
export NODE_ORACLEDB_PASSWORD=NotMyRealPassword
export NODE_ORACLEDB_CONNECTIONSTRING=hostname:1521/servicename
```

hostname is the alias of the server

**docker build**

```
docker build --no-cache --force-rm=true -t node_oracle_app .
```

**docker run**

```
docker run -it -p 9090:9090 -e NODE_ORACLEDB_USER=$NODE_ORACLEDB_USER -e NODE_ORACLEDB_PASSWORD=$NODE_ORACLEDB_PASSWORD -e NODE_ORACLEDB_CONNECTIONSTRING=$NODE_ORACLEDB_CONNECTIONSTRING ade_openlot3_server_oracle
```

Comment: The error does mean your DB is accessible from the application container, which is good.  The problem appears to be your connection string.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/error-help/db/ora-12504/. If you log directly into the container can you connect to the DB using SQL*Plus with a connection string?

Comment: A side comment: you are using 19.3 Instant Client.  This is very old.  The latest is 19.20 Upgrading won't fix your immediate problem but you should keep up to date where possible.

Comment: @Christopher, thanks for the comment, the SERVICE_NAME is there is tnsnames.ora but no SID in CONNECT_DATA component, the connection works completely fine with the same connection string when the app is hosted locally in my own PC.

Comment: @Christpher, I tried to log into the container using sqlplus command but it says: sqlplus: command not found.

Answer (score 1):

I you want to access an Oracle Database running in one container from another container you should use a docker network.

Before running the two container create a network:

```bash
$ docker network create oraclenet
```

When running each container add the `--network` command line argument:

```bash
$ docker run ... --network="oraclenet"
```

When now connecting to the Oracle Database from you application, just use the container name of the Oracle Server as the host name.
Assuming the Oracle Database container is named `oracledb`:

```bash
$ export NODE_ORACLEDB_CONNECTIONSTRING=oracledb:1521/servicename
```

Comment: @dockerkofler, thanks for your effort, however question was not to connect an Oracle Database running in one container from another container, question was to connect to an Oracle database which is hosted on a server (Not in Docker) from my nodejs app hosted in a Docker container

Comment: In that case, I would first make sure, that the app can connect to the database independently from  docker. Did you try to run the application outside the container and does that work? If not there is something wrong with the oracledb and/or oracle client installation independently from Docker.

Comment: this app was developed way before and it is running in localhost of my PC and all is fine. Now we want to dockerize all our apps

Comment: If you can connect to the server from your local host, we should check the Oracle Database itself. Can you connect to the Database when for example using sqlplus?